# What is the difference between alias and export (and a function!)[BASH]?

Tags: bash, shell, command, zsh, apropos

I'm surprised hasn't been asked before, but…

What is the difference between

*alias*   ⇢ `alias EXPORT='alias'`

*function*   ⇢ `function exporter() { echo $EXPORT }`

and

*export*    ⇢  `export ALIAS='export'`

and for that matter...

`alias export=$(function)`  (j/k)

in `bash` (`zsh`, et al.)

Specifically, I'd be most interested in knowing the lexical/practical difference between

```
alias this=that
```

and

```
export that=this
```

I have *both forms*... *all over the place* - and would prefer to stop arbitrarily choosing one, over the other.

I'm sure there is a great reference to a "scopes and use-cases for unix shells", somewhere... but thought I'd post the question here, in the name of *righteous-canonicalicism*.

Comment: Moreover, I'm afraid that the way your question is phrased, it seems __too broad__.

Comment: http://links.mrgray.com/doesntexist

Comment: Unfortunately, your example do not help in understanding what your doubt is or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: As a general rule, always prefer functions over aliases (unless you know that an alias is preferable, which only very rarely happens).

Comment: Your profile suggests that you are familiar with C.  You could think of aliases being similar to `#define`s and functions are like, of course, functions.

Comment: You may want to `my_alias() { my_command "$@"; }` to simulate exporting aliases

Answer (score 33):

You're asking about two very different categories of things: aliases and functions define things that act like commands; `export` marks a variable to be exported to child processes. Let me go through the command-like things first:

An alias (`alias ll='ls -l'`) defines a shorthand for a command. They're intended for interactive use (they're actually disabled by default in shell scripts), and are simple but inflexible. For example, any arguments you specify after the alias simply get tacked onto the end of the command; if you wanted something like `alias findservice='grep "$1" /etc/services'`, you can't do it, because `$1` doesn't do anything useful here.

A function is like a more flexible, more powerful version of an alias. Functions can take & process arguments, contain loops, conditionals, here-documents, etc... Basically, anything you could do with a shell script can be done in a function. Note that the standard way to define a function doesn't actually use the keyword `function`, just parentheses after the name. For example: `findservice() { grep "$1" /etc/services; }`

Ok, now on to shell variables. Before I get to `export`, I need to talk about unexported variables. Basically, you can define a variable to have some (text) value, and then if you refer to the variable by `$variablename` it'll be substituted into the command. This differs from an alias or function in two ways: an alias or function can only occur as the first word in the command (e.g. `ll filename` will use the alias `ll`, but `echo ll` will not), and variables must be explicitly invoked with `$` (`echo $foo` will use the variable foo, but `echo foo` will not). More fundamentally, aliases and functions are intended to contain executable code (commands, shell syntax, etc), while variables are intended to store non-executable data.

(BTW, you should almost always put variable references inside double-quotes -- that is, use `echo "$foo"` instead of just `echo $foo`. Without double-quotes the variable's contents get parsed in a somewhat weird way that tends to cause bugs.)

There are also some "special" shell variables, that are automatically set by the shell (e.g. `$HOME`), or influence how the shell behaves (e.g. `$PATH` controls where it looks for executable commands), or both.

An `export`ed variable is available both in the current shell, and also passed to any subprocesses (subshells, other commands, whatever). For example, if I do `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, that tells my current shell use the "en_US.UTF-8" locale settings. On the other hand, if I did `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` that would tell the current shell *and all subprocesses and commands it executes* to use that locale setting.

Note that a shell variable can be marked as exported separately from defining it, and once exported it stays exported. For example, `$PATH` is (as far as I know) *always* exported, so `PATH=/foo:/bar` has the same effect as `export PATH=/foo:/bar` (although the latter may be preferred just in case $PATH somehow wasn't already exported).

It's also possible to export a variable to a particular command *without* defining it in the current shell, by using the assignment as a prefix for the command. For example `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 sort filename` will tell the `sort` command to use the "en_US.UTF-8" locale settings, but not apply that to the current shell (or any other commands).

Comment: great answer..  to follow up.. what is the scope of declared `alias` and functions?  are they also available to subshells/child processes, etc? if not, is export a mechanism that could force that kind of inheritance?

Comment: In your answer it seems that only variables can be flagged as exported. Functions too can be exported: `fun() { echo hello; }; bash -c 'fun'` will raise a `bash: fun: command not found` error, but after `export -f fun`, `bash -c 'fun'` will say hello `:)`.

Comment: bash allows functions to be exported (with `export -f`), but this is a bash-only feature -- I don't know of any other shells that can export functions, or that will understand functions exported to them by bash. So, the capability is sort of there but it's nonstandard and a bit weird. Also, as far as I know, no shell supports exporting aliases.

Comment: Good answer.  One little work-around to get aliases to work in shell scripts is to use `source` for the shell script.  For instance,  I have some aliases which I like to use interactively.  I also have a script which applies a command to a bunch of local GIT repositories.  I would like to use the aliases with the script that reruns them in all those places.  To do this I defined my `apply` alias as `source do-command-everywhere.sh`.  Works fine (as long as you don't use `exit`!) because the script is just run in the current process.

Comment: source will only work with interactive shell. if you have a library script with a function and an alias you may source it and the alias will work, but if you do the same source in another script it will not work by default. you need "shopt -s expand_aliases" for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

1. The shell evaluation order (per POSIX) for the entities in your question is:
   `aliases --> variables --> command substitutions --> special built-ins --> functions --> regular built-ins`
2. Aliases do not persist across subshells, but variables (and in Bash, functions) can be made to do so with the `export` command.
3. Regular built-ins can be overridden by writing functions that have the same name as the regular built-in (since functions expand before regular built-ins). (*NOTE: If you're trying to add functionality to the regular built-in, call the built-in with `command` in your function definition so you don't accidentally create a recursive function.*)
4. Variables can be made readonly with the (special built-in) `readonly` command, but aliases cannot.

**USE CASES:**

1. Export a variable if you need to use a variable across subshells.
2. Make a variable `readonly` if you don't want it changed for the life of the parent shell (once performed, this cannot be undone with `unset`; you must restart the parent shell).
3. If you want to override or add functionality to a regular built-in, use a function.

**NOTE:** *If you want to be sure that you're using a special or regular built-in and not someone else's function, use* `builtin the_builtin`, *or if the shell doesn't support the* `builtin` *command, use the POSIX comand* `command -p the_builtin`, *where the* `-p` *switch tells command to use the $PATH that ships with the shell by default (in case the user has overriden path).*

**NOTE:** *A variable can be made to act like an alias that also persists across subshells and cannot be changed. For example,*

```sh
#! /bin/sh

my_cmd='ls -al'
export my_cmd
readonly my_cmd
```

*will act like*

```sh
#! /bin/sh

alias my_cmd='ls -al'
```

*so long as*

1. `my_cmd` *is used without double-quotes (i.e.* `${my_cmd}`, ***NOT*** `"${my_cmd}"`*) so it isn't treated as a single string, and*
2. `IFS` *is the standard* `space-tab-newline` *and not switched to something else so that the elements of* `my_cmd` *are globbed and each part separated by a space is evaluated as a single token (otherwise it will be evaluated as a single string).*

Each shell (e.g. `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, `yash`, etc.) is a bit different, so be sure to review the reference manual for it (they each implement POSIX in a unique way, or sometimes not at all).