# Bash what bash alias actually is?

Tags: bash

I realised I've been using bash aliases without really understanding what they are.

To give an example I have following alias in my .bashrc for a quick access to workspace folder.

```
alias workspace='cd $HOME/workspace'
```

It seems that I can also write this as

```
function workspace {
        cd "$HOME/workspace"
}
```

For the same effect. Is alias just a shorthand for a commonly used functions or is there some difference?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23172982/3776858

Comment: And read `man 1P alias`, *"The alias utility shall create or redefine alias definitions or write the values of existing alias definitions to standard output..."*