# export doesn't work to change the execution path

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
export ab=~/local/bin/ab
which ab
```

`which` is printing `/bin/ab`.

From other environments when I print `which ab`, it prints `~/local/bin/ab`

Comment: See my answer to [What is the difference between alias and export (and a function!)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172982/what-is-the-difference-between-alias-and-export-and-a-functionbash).

Comment: @hellofanengineer : The _export_ statement is used to manipulate environment variables.  Try `printenv ab` to see the value of `ab`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export ab` creates a variable named `$ab`. To make a shortcut to the executable, add the directory to your path:

```
# add this to ~/.bashrc to make it permanent
PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH
```

Or create a function:

```
ab() { ~/local/bin/ab "$@"; }
```

Or an alias:

```
alias ab='~/local/bin/ab'
```

---

**Note:** On many systems `~/bin` will already be in your `$PATH`. All you have to do is create it if it doesn't exist and move the executable there.

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
mv ~/local/bin/ab ~/bin
```

Comment: Followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878854/alias-doesnt-affect-python-execution-environment-in-bash @JohnKugelman