# alias doesn't affect python execution environment in bash

Tags: python, bash, node-modules

I'm getting error while executing my shell script

```
alias abs='~/local/bin/abs'
echo $(which abs)
source /home/rundeck/.bashrc # included alias abs as well. I'm just sourcing it twice.
python batch_update_autobuilds.py <- I'm getting an error here
```

`($which abs)` prints,,,

```
alias abs='~/local/bin/abs'
        ~/local/bin/abs
```

batch_update_autobuilds.py source code (Where the error is coming from)

```
abscommand = "abs update --test" // --test tag has been recently updated. 
commandline = subprocess.Popen((abscommand))
output, error = commandline.communicate()
if error: <- error got caught here. //So it says no option available for --test.
```

Problem:

- Somehow when I call the bash execution command `commandline.communicate()`, **it calls the old `abs` which doesn't have `--test` option**.

Possible Solution(need help):

- I copied `abs` execution file to `~/local/bin` and I want to force python execution to use the `abs` in `~/local/bin`; alias didn't work in this case.

Comment: By default aliases are only expanded in interactive shells.

Comment: @Barmar oh how do we expand it to default bash profile or somewhere???

Comment: `shopt -s expand_aliases` will enable aliases in a non-interactive shell.

Comment: Why don't you just put `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` instead of using an alias?

Comment: Maybe you could declare a function rather than an alias

Comment: # .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

alias abs='~/local/bin/abs'

Comment: @Barmar ok? I'm in /user/local/bin and I see `bin`, jq, node, nodejs, npx, python; `abs` was originally installed by npm. Now I have a local as `~/local/bin/abs`

Comment: So put `~/local/bin` in your `$PATH`

Comment: In your `.profile`, put `PATH=~/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: just added it in .bashrc.

Comment: damn it worked? why wasn't it working before ha

Comment: Spent literally a whole day on this